# Noun for an irresponsible person in a position of power

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am wanting a noun for an irresponsible, careless, inconsiderate person who is in a position of power or control or leadership. For example:

```
[noun]s are the downfall of our system.
```

Comment: In before Donald Trump joke answers ...

Comment: @Glorfindel I was attempting to be vague, but it's not easy...

Comment: Political sock puppet: https://thecaucus.blogs.nytimes.com/2007/02/23/unmasking-the-sock-puppets/?_r=0

Comment: @Josh Kind of, but I feel that has the connotation of others being in control, rather than the individual being reckless/irresponsible of their own accord.

Comment: @Glorfindel But not in before Nero, who [ruled irresponsibly 2,000 years ago](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero).

Comment: I'm making this one up: [maladministrators](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maladministration).

Comment: @Glorfindel oh no you're not ;) https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maladministrator

Comment: @DanBron You could just call someone a "Nero," or wait 50 years and call him "Trump"

Comment: Where is the historical awareness on this site? No George Bush jokes?

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/despot

Answer (score 1):

## Incompetent

### Dictionary definitions

> [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incompetent):"someone who does not have the ability or skill to do something as it should be done"
>
> [*dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/incompetent): "an incompetent person; a mentally deficient person."
>
> [*Macmillan Dictionary*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/incompetent_2):"someone who lacks the ability or skills to do something"
>
> [*Oxford Living Dictionary*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incompetent):"An incompetent person."

---

> [*Oxford Living Dictionary*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incompetent) (on the adjective):
>
> "Not having or showing the necessary skills to do something successfully."
>
> "Not qualified to act in a particular capacity."

### Examples (suited for your question)

The first three are taken from [Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incompetent), the last is taken from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/incompetent).

> "‘After reading an article in a daily newspaper this week I am left to conclude that our elected leaders are a bunch of fools, **incompetents** and idiots (take your pick as to who falls into which category).’"
>
> "‘History is littered with despots and psychopaths, murderous dullards, evil geniuses, deadly **incompetents**, calamitous brutes of all descriptions.’"
>
> "‘At best they have been portrayed as bungling **incompetents**.’"
>
> "The country's being governed by a bunch of **incompetents**."

### OP's sentence

> **Incompetents** are the downfall of our system.